# Phabricator linter can't find any lintable paths

Tags: json, regex, pylint, phabricator

How can I configure phabricator to lint only files that match `*py`?

The following is my .arclint file:

```
{
  "linters": {
    "pylint": {
      "type": "pylint",
      "include": "(\\.py$)"
    }
  }
}
```

which is based heavily on the examples found here:
https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/arcanist_lint/

When I run it I get this:

```
$ arc lint 
No paths are lintable.
```

If I remove the include line it tries to lint every file, so it must be something wrong with the regular expression: `"(\\.py$)"` which to be honest looks weird to me but is exactly what I found in the examples.  And `"(*.py)"`, `"*.py"`, and `"^*.py$"` are all invalid regular expressions.

Comment: nope, no luck with that either

Comment: and `\.py\$` doesn't work? Or `"\(\\\\.py\$\)"` if you want whole part. However regex is not the best tool to parse Json

Comment: both of those actually cause a JSON parsing exception

Answer (score 28, accepted):

So it turns out there's actually nothing wrong with the regular expression.  I'm just not using `arc lint` correctly.

The `arc lint` command only tries to lint files that have been modified.  I was just expecting it to behave like `arc lint --everything`.

```
$ arc lint --help

  lint [options] [paths]
  lint [options] --rev [rev]
      Supports: git, svn, hg
      Run static analysis on changes to check for mistakes. If no files
      are specified, lint will be run on all files which have been modified.
```